# I want to delete in dao with spring 4 framework. but MariaDB error occur. but I use xampp db

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to delete in dao with spring 4 framework. but `MariaDB` error occurs. but I use `XAMPP db`

**My code is**

```
@Override
    public void makeDelete(Long id) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("delete from Employee c where c.id:id")
        .setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
```

Comment: `c.id:id` should be `c.id = :id`.

Comment: You seem confused about the MariaDB error since you use [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP). XAMPP include Maria DB for the persistence layer ... seems legit then. The error is explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"where c.id:id"` to `"where c.id = :id"`.